# What's problem when i delete "insmod..." and "search..." lines in custom grub file

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

What is the difference when i delete the "insmod ntfs" line and the "search..." line in this custom grub file?

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {

insmod ntfs

set root='(hd0,1)'

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set a3f1ea41fc67a3f1

chainloader +1

}
```